# Reassigning function to a value

Tags: julia

I don't understand why exactly is happening/why I am not getting an error when doing `somefunc() = 100`? Now when I "call" `somefunc`, it outputs `100`. I also tried just doing `somefunc = 100`, which then gives me an error. After reassigning `somefunc()` to `100`, when I just write `somefunc`, it still says it is a function.

What exactly is happening here? Why do I get an error when reassigning `somefunc` to a value, but when reassigning `somefunc()`, not? Why does `somefunc` still say it is a function, even after reassigning it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `somefunc() = 100` in global scope you define a new method for the `somefunc` function. This has two effects:

1. If `somefunc` is undefined, make it a constant (i.e. cannot be reassigned like `const x = 123`) binding to a new generic function.
2. Whether it's new or not add a method for `() -> 100` to the `somefunc` generic function object.

The fact that the binding for `somefunc` is constant is why you cannot reassign it afterwards. This is very important for performance since non-constant globals have quite bad performance; if function bindings were not constant then any time you called a function it would be slow.

Even though you cannot change what function `somefunc` refers to, you can change the function itself by adding methods to it or even overriding existing ones. For example, writing later `somefunc() = 200` does not create a new function, but rather replaces the method of this function taking no arguments with a new method that returns 200 instead of 100.

When you write:

```
somefunc() = 100
```

it is just a shorthand for

```
function somefunc()
    return 100
end
```

So even though there is a `=` sign, that is an assignment operator it is not the same as writing `x = 100`, which simply binds the value `100` the name `x`. In particular note that writing e.g.:

```
somefunc = () -> 100
```

allows you to write `somefunc()`, and get `100`. But this time you are free to write later `somefunc = 100`, as `somefunc = () -> 100` is not a function definition but rather it is na assignment that binds the anonymous function `() -> 100` to the name `somefunc`.

Comment: Another key fact is that function bindings crated by the method declaration syntaxes are constant. Otherwise you would be able to reassign.

Comment: I hoped to express it :): I have updated the text so hopefully now it is clearer.